# Magento 2 - Can't override class - must be an instance of

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin, di, preference

I created a preference override for Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemPersister in my own module. But I get this error in the browser developer console:

> Total: Type Error occurred when creating object:
> ***Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ShippingAssignment\ShippingAssignmentProcessor***,
> Argument 3 passed to
> Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ShippingAssignment\ShippingAssignmentProcessor::__construct()
> **must be an instance** of **Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemPersister**
>
> instance of
> **Company\Configurator\Rewrite\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemPersister** given

#### app/code/Company/Configurator/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemPersister"
                type="Company\Configurator\Rewrite\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemPersister"/>
      ...
```

It seems like I also have to override **Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ShippingAssignment\ShippingAssignmentProcessor** and swap to my rewrite class there, but this does not seem to be the official way?

UPDATE: I've completly overriden Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ShippingAssignment\ShippingAssignmentProcessor but now I get

> Total: Type Error occurred when creating object:
> Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\LoadHandler\Interceptor, Argument
> 1 passed to
> Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\LoadHandler\Interceptor::__construct()
> must be an instance of
> Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ShippingAssignment\ShippingAssignmentProcessor,
> instance of
> Company\Configurator\Rewrite\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ShippingAssignment\ShippingAssignmentProcessor
> given, called in
> /var/www/company/m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
> on line 121

Whats the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it with a plugin instead of an override

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your only option would be to create a subclass of `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemPersister` and implement your changes there. This can get messy when the parent class implements a lot of private methods which usually means that you need to copy the parent class to the subclass and then add your customizations on top.